# What could be the usage of material declaration datasheet for Spartan-6 package?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan-6

I'm starting to work with FPGAs and CPLDs. like other professional EEs when I bought a Spartan-6 board, started to search in the website of manufacture (that was Xilinx) to find everything about my component. well there is a bunch of good articles and stuffs.

One of these articles is [Material Declaration datasheet for Spartan-6 package](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/package_specs/pk648_cs225.pdf). But the question is that What could be the usage of these datasheet?

How could it help to an EE?

to make it simple for you guys, I converted this datasheet to image and put it here:

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The materials declaration is used if your product needs to comply with [RoHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive) or other regulatory restrictions on material content.

RoHS not only requires that your product not contain certain materials, but also that you document this fact. Typically, in order to do that, you need to request the vendors of all the components in your design to provide a material declaration like the one you showed. This documentation isn't just needed for the chips but also the pcb laminates, the soldermask, the solder, the adhesive stickers with the serial number, etc.